# Showing that similar matrices have the same minimal polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, minimal-polynomials

I am in the process of proving the title.

The hint says, for any polynomial $f$, we have $$f(P^{-1}AP) = P^{-1}f(A)P.$$ A is an $n \times n$ matrix over $F$ while $P$ is an invertible matrix such that the above matrix multiplication $P^{-1}AP$ makes sense.

Why is this true?

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: What is $(P^{-1}AP)^n$?

Comment: @user60589 It is  $P^{-1}A^nP$

Comment: Can you use this with the fact that $f$ is polynomial?

Comment: That would be useful if the OP wanted to prove the hint - but I think the task is to prove that similar matrices have the same minimal polynomial

Comment: @user60589 aha! got it. Thanks. Also thank you WW1 but I think I know how to proceed from here!

Comment: @SeojunHong if you think you have an answer (and if you care to share it), feel free to post an answer to your own question.

Comment: Related post (duplicate?): [to prove $f(P^{-1}AP)=P^{-1}f(A)P$ for an $n\times{n}$ square matrix?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/686044/to-prove-fp-1ap-p-1fap-for-an-n-timesn-square-matrix)

Comment: nice question    .............+1

Answer (score 6):

if $f$ is a polynomial then you have:
$$f(x)=a_nx^n+...+a_1x+a_0$$
Then you have
$$f(P^{-1}AP)=a_n(P^{-1}AP)^n+...+a_1(P^{-1}AP)+a_0I$$
which is
$$f(P^{-1}AP)=a_n(P^{-1}APP^{-1}AP...P^{-1}AP)+...+a_1(P^{-1}AP)+a_0P^{-1}IP$$
or
$$f(P^{-1}AP)=P^{-1}a_nA^nP+...+P^{-1}a_1AP+a_0P^{-1}IP$$
which finally gives
$$f(P^{-1}AP)=P^{-1}(a_nA^n+...+a_1A+a_0I)P=P^{-1}f(A)P$$

Answer (score 0):

Letting $ev_M$ be the evaluation map of $M$ for all $M \in M_n(K)$, we can prove that $\ker (ev_A) = \ker (ev_B)$.

To do that it suffices to show that for all $Q \in K[X]$, $P(A) = 0$ iff $Q(B) = 0$ (by symmetry we can prove just one direction of the implication).

So take $Q \in K[X]$ and write $Q = \sum_{i=0} a_i X^i$. Suppose $Q(A) = 0$. Then:

$0 = P^{-1}Q(A)P = \sum_{i=0} a_i P^{-1}A^iP = \sum_{i=0} a_i (P^{-1}AP)^i = \sum_{i=0} a_i B^i = Q(B)$.

Therefore we have $\ker (ev_A) \subset \ker (ev_B)$. By symmetry $\ker (ev_A) = \ker (ev_B)$, which gives us the desired result.